# devise helper methods undefined in custom class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've been hunting down this bug for a bit... my helper methods don't seem to be defined. Or they're being defined incorrectly. `user_unlock_url` is a specific example.

My controller follows the wiki:

```
class MyDeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
  helper :application # gives access to all helpers defined within `application_helper`.
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers # Optional. eg. `confirmation_url`
  # Ensure that the mailer uses the devise views
  default template_path: 'devise/mailer'
  ...
end
```

but when calling it, it fails

```
> MyDeviseMailer.unlock_instructions(User.first, 'token').deliver_now
Rendering devise/mailer/unlock_instructions.html.erb within layouts/mailer
Rendered devise/mailer/unlock_instructions.html.erb within layouts/mailer (9.2ms)
MyDeviseMailer#unlock_instructions: processed outbound mail in 236.1ms
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `user_unlock_url' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy:0x00007fcfc621cd78> 
from /Users/brett.dudo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/routes_proxy.rb:50:in `method_missing'
Caused by NoMethodError: undefined method `user_unlock_url' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy:0x00007fcfc621cd78> 
from /Users/brett.dudo/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/routes_proxy.rb:50:in `method_missing'
```

I checked to see if the helper was initializing properly:

```
> mappings = Devise.mappings.values.map(&:used_helpers).flatten.uniq
=> [:session, :password, :registration, :unlock, :authy, :passwords_with_policy, :invitation]

> routes = Devise::URL_HELPERS.slice(*mappings)
=> {:session=>[nil, :new, :destroy],
 :password=>[nil, :new, :edit],
 :registration=>[nil, :new, :edit, :cancel],
 :unlock=>[nil, :new],
 :authy=>[],
 :passwords_with_policy=>[],
 :invitation=>[nil, :new, :accept]} 

> routes.each do |module_name, actions|
*   [:path, :url].each do |path_or_url|
*     actions.each do |action|
*       action = action ? "#{action}_" : ""
*       puts "#{action}#{module_name}_#{path_or_url}"
*     end
*   end
* end

...
unlock_path
new_unlock_path
unlock_url
new_unlock_url
...
```

and it seems to be included, but why is `user_` being prepended?? That seems to be my problem, but I can't figure out why.

My mailer is definitely using the correct value:

```
<p><%= link_to 'Unlock my account', unlock_url(@resource, unlock_token: @token, host: @site_host) %></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

What's in your devise_for ?

```
  devise_for :users, :path=> 'members', only: :omniauth_callbacks, controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks'}
```

What comes after devise_for (:user) gets prepended to path and url helpers

Comment: That clarifies the the route being generated. It is `users`. It doesn't explain the `undefined method 'user_unlock_url'`, unfortunately. Any ideas?